# android - setItemChecked is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to make one checkbox checked if the dialog is opened, but setItemChecked doesn't seem to be working.. Here is my code. I already checked other answers, but it doesn't help. Does anybody know if there is something wrong with my code?

Thanks.

```
        alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.list_array, list_values, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have selected " + list[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            int size = checkedItems.size();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Save " + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    if (isAlreadyOpened) {
        alertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(4, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your applied code   if (isAlreadyOpened) is not working...
Due to false condition at the time of the statement execution.

Just set

```
 alertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(4, true);
```

before you show the dialog at the time of creation of dialog

Comment: I simplified the code by removing the if statement to see if it works, but it still doesn't work...  alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(4, true);alertDialog.show();

Comment: I found the workaround. I am changing the boolean value for list_values. it is working the way I want...